# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am using dataflow kafka to bigquery template. after launching the dataflow job, it stays in queue for some time then fails with below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

While lauching job, i have provided below parameters:

1. kafka topic name
2. bootstrap server ip and port (private ip)
3. bigquery topic name
4. SA email
5. zone.
6. Network , subnet (same network where kafka server running)

My kafka topic only contanis message: hello

kafka is installed in gcp instance which is in same zone and subnet as dataflow worker.

Comment: The issue seems to be on the side of Kafka, a possible solution is mentioned in the following [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254686/timeoutexception-timeout-expired-while-fetching-topic-metadata-kafka) where is mentioned that the issue can happen when trying to connect to a broker expecting SSL connections and the client config did not specify and the solution is to set the security protocol to SSL:

`security.protocol=SSL`

Comment: Make sure your Kafka broker `listeners` properties are setup to bind externally

Comment: Hey Thanks @OneCricketeer , i was trying to access kafka with internal ip. it worked when i ched it to public ip. Actually i am running both kafka machines and workers in same subnet. so it should work with internal ip also... i am checking it now

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved. i was trying to access kafka bootstrap server with internal ip. it worked when i changed it to public ip.